# Keep PyGTK Button from Resizing on Label Change

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pygtk

I'm working on a PyGTK app with some Buttons that, when clicked, give a text entry dialog, then set the text on the button to whatever was entered in the box. The problem is that if the text is longer than the button can show, the button changes size to accomodate. How do I keep GTK Buttons from resizing when the text changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried set_size_request?

http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-size-request

```
button = gtk.Button("text on button")
button.set_size_request(width=30, height=20)
```

See:
http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-size-request

In glade, you can set "Width request" in the "Common" tab.